# Python: Making a read-only property accessible via **vars(some_class)

Tags: python, dictionary, properties

I often use the idiom `'{var_name}'.format(**vars(some_class))`.

However, when I use a property, I cannot use this to get the properties value.

Consider this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None
        self.baz = 'baz here'

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not self._bar:
            # calculate some value...
            self._bar = 'bar here'
        return self._bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()

    # works:
    print('{baz}'.format(**vars(foo)))

    # gives: KeyError: 'bar'
    print('{bar}'.format(**vars(foo)))
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to make a properties value accessible via `**vars(some_class)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's not possible to use `.format(**vars(object))` to do what you want, since properties do **not** use `__dict__` and from `vars` documentation:

> `vars(...)`
>
> `vars([object])` -> dictionary
>
> - Without arguments, equivalent to `locals()`.
> - With an argument, equivalent to `object.__dict__`.

However you can achieve what you want using different format specifiers, for example the attribute lookup:

```
In [2]: '{.bar}'.format(Foo())
Out[2]: 'bar here'
```

Note that you simply have to add a leading `.` (dot) to the names and you get exactly what you want.

---

Side note: instead of using `.format(**vars(object))` you should use the `format_map` method:

```
In [6]: '{baz}'.format_map(vars(Foo()))
Out[6]: 'baz here'
```

Calling `format_map` with a `dict` argument is equivalent to calling `format` using the `**` notation, but it is more efficient, since it doesn't have to do any kind of unpacking before calling the function.

Comment: +1, attribute lookup it is then, also I didn't know about `format_map`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` notation -

`print('{0._bar}'.format(foo))`

Comment: Just noticed the bottom part where you ask for something using `**vars(some_class)` is this really a requirement?

Comment: If you give up the `**vars(some_class)`, you can also use the property getter: `print('{0.bar}'.format(foo))`.

Comment: Yes this works, but it should say `print('{0.bar}'.format(foo))` (without the underscore), otherwise the property wouldn't make sense ;D

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly what you asked for, you can write a class that translates item access to attribute access:

```
class WrapperDict(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.obj, key)
```

Example:

```
>>> print('{bar}'.format_map(WrapperDict(Foo())))
bar here
```

Another rather hacky alternative would be to add

```
__getitem__ = object.__getattribute__
```

to the class `Foo` and then use the `Foo` instance directly:

```
>>> print('{bar}'.format_map(Foo()))
bar here
```

I think using attribute access notation is the better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, something like this should work:

```
print( eval( 'foo.{bar}'.format( **dict( ( v, v ) for v in dir( foo ) ) ) ) )
```

But nevertheless this feels somehow "very bad".

Comment: Works, but I don't like to use `eval`...better: `print('{bar}'.format(**dict((v, getattr(foo,v)) for v in dir(foo))))`, but it's not terribly elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it into `__dict__` of your instance

```
class Article(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = ""
        self.url = ""

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.__dict__.get("title", "")

    @title.setter
    def title(self, title):
        self.__dict__["title"] = title
```

then:

```
>>> article = Article()
>>> article.title = "Awesome Title"
>>> vars(article)
{'content': '', 'url': '', 'title': 'Awesome Title'}
```